# How to iterate over array and do a callback function for every five seconds?

Tags: javascript, asynchronous

I don't want to use a setTimeinterval function every-time as mentioned here [Loop every five seconds in Javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28697839/loop-every-five-seconds-in-javascript) as it is not iterating over an array but looping it for every five seconds. But I want something that needs to execute after every five seconds till iteration of array elements is done.

```js
const csv = require('csv-parser');
const fs = require('fs');
const results = [];
fs.createReadStream('csvlist1.csv')
    .pipe(csv())
    .on('data', (data) => results.push(data))
    .on('end', () => {
        results.forEach((e) => setTimeout(() => log(e), 1000));
    });

function log(e) {
    console.log(e);
}
```

consider the above code. When it is executed it should print the elements in the results array one by one after every 1 second. Thank's in advance.

Comment: why the jQuery tag?

Comment: Actually, `setTimeout`  appears to be exactly what you want.

Comment: setTimeout() is a time function.